# Got TypeError: expect(...).toBeInTheDocument is not a function even after proper setup

Tags: jest-dom

I use Create React App and already declare this on src/setupTests.js:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

But every time I use `expect(anything).toBeInTheDocument()` on test file, when running the test I get:

```
TypeError: expect(...).toBeInTheDocument is not a function
```

To make sure that the setupTests.js is actually run, I try to use enzyme shallow on test file and it works. So what is the problem with jest-dom actually and how to solve it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Solved with:

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
```

on src/setupTests.js

Comment: For me I had to do `pnpm add -D @types/testing-library__jest-dom` and I had no need to import anything anywhere

Answer (score 12):

It is easier to add in your `jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...,
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
  ]
}
```

and to create `jest.setup.js` with the content

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

With that you don't have to import the jest-dom in every test file